# How to carry wood logs in the Legends-of-Andor?

Tags: legends-of-andor

Playing the legends of Andor, we are asked to transport wood logs to reconstruct villages.

The rules state [my translation from french]:

> 1. The logs are placed on the hero board, on the cells left of the cube indicating the hero strength.
>    "Les Rondins sont placés sur la fiche du Héros, sur les cases situées à gauche du cube indiquant le nombre de ses Points de Force."
>    Example: to carry a second log, the hero need at least 3 of strength.

[image]

If I have 3 of strength, so the cube on the "3", how could 2 logs be put there?

[image]

To me, either we would need force 5 (so there are 4 spaces to place the logs, because each of them have the size of 2 stength cells).
or
We would need force 4, by placing the logs on top.

I don't understand how placing the logs left, we could place 2 logs having 3 of strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that part in the French rulebook too, and I assume it's actually a translation mistake.

If you look at the same passage in the English rulebook:

> The logs are placed on the hero board’s strength point track — fitting to the left of the cube that indicates the strength points. *Example: To be able to carry a “2” log, the hero needs at least 3 strength points.*

So it should not be read as "*to be able to carry a second log*", but instead as "*to be able to carry a log of size 2*".

Comment: All right, that makes sense. Thank you